# VisualStudio says GitHub repository already exists but Github says it does not

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a new GitHub repo by Visual Studio Code, but when I created it got this message:
**[image: strong text]**

But actually i have no repo (public or private) named "INF256-Tarea-1" as you can see here:
[image]

This is what Git Output says:

```
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Using git 2.27.0.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
> git rev-parse --git-dir
Open repository: c:\Users\lilkimo\Desktop\Universidad\INF256\INF256-Tarea-1
> git fetch
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
```

I do nothing strange, only click the 'Initialize Repository' Button, make the commit and push it.

Comment: What happens if you try to clone it? `git clone git@github.com/lilkimo/INF256-Tarea-1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a vscode (Git) BUG!!!!
My way is

1. create a repository on github.com
2. Vscode Clone Git from github
3. rename local fileName and copy .git
4. create a folder with your repository name
5. copy you .git folder to your location

Answer (score 1):

First create a repo from github desktop then just use this on VS

Answer (score 0):

If you have GitHub Desktop installed you can add an existing repository and upload that to GitHub, which should then immediately show in vscode as being linked, you can then check this with the command `git remote -v`, which should now show the linked repo on GitHub.